# Dynamic add images in a horizontall listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

I am getting images from the server which i needs to add in a single rows means in a  horizontal list view .How can i do this please help?

Thanks

Comment: see [this].(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353340/android-how-to-add-a-custom-horizontal-scrollview-to-list-of-images/20070897#20070897)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Horizontal listview](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34). example in Android

Answer (score 0):

Start checking for horizontal listview implementations, like this one:

https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/blob/master/devsmartlib/src/com/devsmart/android/ui/HorizontalListView.java